# Manga where two college students meet God, and are inseparable for some time, which causes them to fall in love

Tags: story-identification, manga

It starts off with a guy walking to college or something, and a girl that either jumped or was pushed off a high roof lands on him, killing them both.

They then meet God together and he says that they have to live with each other for one week or so. And in that time they can't be separated from each other because they can feel each other's feelings. And at the end of the week, one of them has to die.

At first they don't really like each other, but they gradually fall in love. At one point they go to the girl's mother's grave on a cliff side. They then try to commit suicide together. But then they just come back alive.

I also remember that the guy quite liked drawing.

But in the end the guy ends up volunteering to die. And I think the girl ended up having a kid with him before he died as well.

If you could tell me this manga's name, that would be awesome.

Comment: This is a story-identification question about a manga which involves two people dying, meeting (a) god, and then maybe being resurrected or something, which sounds fantastical. Hence, I have migrated it here. The fantasticality is admittedly a bit tenuous from the description given by OP (it could be one of those things where there is one fantastical element to drive the plot and is otherwise mundane).

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You say they were supposed to be together for "one week or so", but in the end they had a kid before one of them died. There seems to be a huge difference in time scope here - which one is it or what did I understand wrong? Could you please [edit] your question? Also, when did you read this/ when was it created (roughly)? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 9):

**[Half & half](https://myanimelist.net/manga/42545/Half___Half)** by [Kōji Seo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dji_Seo)

[image: cover art]

<sup>Cover art</sup>

Description from [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=36231)

> Nagakawa Shinichi and Sanada Yuuki both get involved in an accident and die together, but they are given a chance to live again. A voice lets them survive for seven more days. However, after the time limit, one of the two must die again.
>
> Also, their lives will be shared, including emotions (guilt) and physical sensations (pain). They are told not to leave the other's side, else both of them will die. Now, with each of them wanting to save his/her own life, how will the next seven days of non-separation be like? Will they get along?

OP's description on

> It starts off with a guy walking to college or something and a girl that either jumped or was pushed off a high roof lands on him, killing them both.
>
> They then meet god together and he says that they have to live with each other for one week or so. And in that time they can't be separated from each other because they can feel each others feelings. And at the end of the week one of them has to die.
>
> At first they don't really like each other, [...]

is (part of) the first volume, which I have read it before.

Comment: Is there any place we can read it online?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd considering the manga hasn't been licensed yet, I'm afraid there's no way to read it online legally unless it's okay in Japanese (which I did on online legal Japanese eBook store during a promo)

Answer (score 0):

I apologise if I'm incorrect, but I think it's "The Day I Became a God"
It's not a manga though, it's an anime, but I think the story is a bit similar to that. I think they animated the manga maybe, I'm not sure to be honest. Theres also "See you in my 19th life" its really similar. I hope this helped and sorry for my English; it's very bad. I learnt it few weeks ago, so I'm not used to it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain a bit about this anime, so we can see how it matches the question?